# Restrict POST Request The Server

Tags: .htaccess, post, get, request

I want to restrict all POST request that comes from other server via `.htacces`
if they try to post any from other server thing they will get redirected to home page or 404 etc.
I tried this

```
<Limit POST>  
order deny,allow  
deny from all 
allow from 127.0.0.1
</Limit>
```

Note:- GET request are allowed from all servers. Only to block POST requests.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me. Maybe you only had to correct the name of .htaccess file. (double "s")

Answer (score 24, accepted):

That block will only prevent POST requests from hosts other than 127.0.0.1, and you will get a 403 Forbidden response. You could try using mod_rewrite and replace the `<LIMIT>` with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST

# allow the server to POST to itself
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127.0.0.1   

# allow POST from trusted users
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !123.456.789.123   

# send all other post requests to 403 forbidden
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
```

If you would prefer to send post request to the home page of your site instead replace `[F]` in the last line with `[R,L]`

You'd replace the `/` with where your "home page" is if it isn't just `/`.

Comment: that's great stuff. Thanks. Quick question.
if i want to allow some more server to allow.
i need to include `RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !SOME IP ADDRES` am i right.

Comment: What about allowing a domain and its subdomains?