# How to block post method on some url in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Is it possible to block POST method on some url like

```
www.mydomain.com/dontposthere
www.mydomain.com/something/againdontposthere
```

in htaccess ?

Comment: I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but try:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11584101/restrict-post-request-the-server

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have access to mod_rewrite, you can check the `REQUEST_METHOD` environment variable and rewrite the url to another page that displays a message saying something like "You are not allowed to post"

Create a page with the message: `/var/www/noPost.php`

```
You are not allowed to post to this page
```

Then use an .htaccess rule like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dontposthere [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/something/againdontposthere
RewriteRule .* /noPost.php [L,QSA]
```

You can create a list of files/folders as conditions to match or even a regex pattern to match multiple files/folders. You would just need to put `[OR]` after all but the last.

Answer (score 3):

Alternative to writing a "noPost" page, simply return a 403 response directly with the [F|forbidden flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/dontposthere
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

### Allow POST requests only from specific URI's

You can block POST methods from all URIs, except a few specific ones allowed (like contact forms, and login froms), using this `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/contact\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/login\.php
RewriteRule ^ / [F]
```

Hope it's been useful for you, and saves you a few hours.